# Unable to format date in an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, datetime-format

I have an array that I want to write to a spreadsheet using getRange().setValues(). I am able to write to the spreadsheet no problem, but the dates allways look like this:

`2012-06-18T07:00:00.000Z`

I am only interested in seeing `2012-06-18`. When I try to format the date using

```
passedArray[0][12] = Utilities.formatDate(passedArray[0][12], "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

or

```
Utilities.formatDate(passedArray[0][12], "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

or

```
ModifiedArray[0][12] = Utilities.formatDate(passedArray[0][12], "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

It produces an unexpected error. The array its self is is created and populated in another function, then stored as a property in JSON format:

```
var array1JSON = [{'array':[array1[i]]}];
UserProperties.setProperty("arrayPassing",JSON.stringify(array1JSON));
```

Then accessed from the other function

```
var array1JSON = JSON.parse(UserProperties.getProperty('arrayPassing'));
var passedArray = array1JSON[0].array;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(passedArray[0][12]), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");`
since the argument in Utilities.formatDate has to be a date object.